# The most elegant way of applying several filters in Ruby #select

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I have a query object in my application that filters data with Array#select method

```
class QueryObject
  def call(filters)
    data = get_data # returns array 
    data = by_param1(data, filter[:param1])
    data = by_param2(data, filter[:param2])
  end

  private

  def by_param1(data, filter)
    data.select { |d| #filtering goes here }
  end

  def by_param2(data, filter)
    data.select { |d| #filtering goes here }
  end
end
```

How could I pass my filtering blocks to Enumerable to apply all filters and chain them?
I know that I can do something like that:

```
data.select { |d| by_param1 && by_param2 }
```

but it's not elegant in my case because I have a lot of filters

Comment: Why not just chaining all conditions `get_data.select { ... }.select { ... }`?

Comment: @spickermann in my case there are a lot of filters, so the code will be very heavy for me. I'm trying to find a way with Enumerable but no luck for now

Comment: Can you give an example of what a filter and the `filter` hash might look like? And will all the filters always be available or is it possible that some should be skipped depending on a condition?

Comment: This is where `[ ... ].all? { _1[o] }` to run all procs with a given `o` object is handy.

Comment: Presumable you want `def call(filter)` rather than `def call(filters)`. Even though `get_data` is not central to your question it's a bit odd that you don't define it in the class or at least suggest it being defined, such as `def get_data; .... ; end`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use #reduce to great effect here.

For example,

```
filter_1 = -> (thing) { thing > 2 }

filter_2 = -> (thing) { thing < 5 }

def better_filter(input)
  input * 7 < 23
end

filters = [filter_1, filter_2, method(:better_filter), :positive?]

array = (0..9).to_a

filters.reduce(array) { |result, filter| result.select(&filter) }

# [3]
```

In the context of your question, it could go like this:

```
class QueryObject
  def call(filters)
    data = get_data # returns array 
    filters.reduce(data) { |result, filter| result.select(&filter) }
  end
end
```

This assumes that `filters` is passed in as an array of objects that respond to `#call`. That could be a lambda, a simple ruby class, or even a symbol, as I showed in the example.

Comment: It is actually an object that responds to `#to_proc` (and returns a `Proc` from this method)  (not `#call`).